# How To Start A JPanel After Switching

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings, cardlayout

I am creating a Pong clone with a menu and the actual game itself. I am using a `CardLayout` to switch between the two `JPanels`.

However, when I switch from the menu to the board (or playing area), the board just sits there and won't accept my keyboard inputs. How do I start it or start the key listening?

**Source code**: https://cg2916@github.com/cg2916/Pong.git

Comment: Actually, I'm stupid. I just realized I needed to request the focus.

Comment: Source code should be posted in this forum. The SSCCE should be short and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestFocusInWindow()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Answer (as recommended to you previously): Don't use a KeyListener. use Key Bindings.

Comment: @Cg2916: Then focus shouldn't matter. Your code link above isn't valid. Even so, better would be to create and post a small test program that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem, an [sscce](http://sscce). this would be of benefit to you even if you don't post it here since it would simplify your debugging immensely.

Answer (score 0):

for CardLayout the listener should have these codes

```
 CardLayout card=(CardLayout) JPanel_with_cardLayout.getLayout();
 card.show(JPanel_with_cardLayout,"cardname of card you want to switch");
```

example:

```
CardLayout card=(CardLayout) JPanel2.getLayout();
card.show(JPanel2,"card4");
```